# Why using laws of motion is giving me wrong answer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

It's an Homework question

```
A body of masss 2kg is driven by an engine a constant power of delivering 1J/s. The body starts from rest and 
moves in a straight line. After 9 seconds, the body has moved a distance of ____(in m)
```

Here are my thoughts regarding approaching this question

## Case-1:

$$p = \frac{w}{t}$$
work done by engine in 9 sec is 
$$W = 1*9=9J$$
Now applying work energy theoram(ground is smooth as they haven't explicitly mentioned anything related to friction)

work done by normal, mg is zero that leaves with $W_{engine}$ and intial velocity is zero so intial KE is also zero.
$$(W)_{engine} = KE_{f} - KE_{i}$$
$$(W)_{engine} = KE_{f} - 0$$
$$9 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$9 = \frac{1}{2}(2)v^2$$
$$9 = v^2$$
$$v = 3m/s$$

**Here I could approach the problem in three sub cases *A* , *B* or *C***

## Case-1(A):

this is what i've personally did

$$v = u + at$$
$$3 = 0 + a(9)$$
$$a = \frac{1}{3}m/s^2$$
$$s = ut + 0.5(a)9^2$$
$$s = (0)t + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3})(81)$$
$$s = 13.5m$$

## Case-1(B):

$$P = FV$$
$$F = \frac{P}{V} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$W = F.S$$
$$S = \frac{W}{F} = \frac{9}{\frac{1}{3}} = 27m$$

## Case-1(C):

$$F = ma$$
$$F = (2)(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{2}{3}$$
$$W = F.S => S = \frac{W}{F} = \frac{9}{\frac{2}{3}} = 13.5m$$

**A** and **C** gave same answer

## Case-2(Correct Solution):

$$
W = P * t
$$
$$W = t$$
$$W = KE_{f}- KE_{i} = KE_{f} - 0 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = t => v = \sqrt{t}$$
$$v = \frac{ds}{dt} => \sqrt{t} = \frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$\int_0^9 \sqrt{t} dt = \int_0^S ds$$
$$S = 18m$$

The question is why didn't my approaches worked? Where did my **Case-1** go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint comes from the integration in the correct answer. This is not a question with constant force or acceleration, that is why calculus shows up.

The engine provides constant *power*. Power = work done / time taken. That means the mass is gaining energy at a constant rate. Now by $KE = 1/2 mv^2$, a constant increase in $KE$ does NOT imply a constant increase in $v$. It does imply a constant increase in $v^2$, but not in $v$. Therefore there is no constant acceleration. That's why the answer you get is incorrect - you've used equations that assume constant acceleration.

Comment: Case 1(B) also assumes constant velocity by using P=FV.